# Multiple _form views on a single create view [Yii]

Tags: php, forms, templates, yii, yii-chtml

I'm trying to merge 3 models to create a fourth one. I have `model1`, `model2` and `model3` and I want to merge them into `modelMaster`. I've also created controllers for all of them. When I call `modelMaster/create` action, I render the `modelMaster/create` view which renders the `modelMaster/_form` view. Inside this `_form` view, I also want to render `model1/_form`, `model2/_form` and a `CHtml::dropDownList()`, wich takes datas from `model3`. However, this doesn't work. How can I combine these three different views into one another?

Comment: What happens when you do this? You said it doesn't work, but what happens? Does the script crash, is no output produced, etc.?

Comment: it nests `form` elements! so also if I click on the main submit button it does nothing!

Comment: well you have to show the code you have now, in your form. and also tell what exact behavior you want, i.e how do you want the forms to behave, if you don't want nesting. please be a little more clear on your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to skip the form generate from the _form views and use unique model names, I think  you can use this manual: [single form with more models](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/)
So the generate of the form definition handles always the parent view and the _form's only the inputs

The other way to use single model in views, create a form model by extend CFormModel, and handle the data binding between this model and the wrapped submodels

Answer (score 1):

If you want to nest several forms into one master form you have to adjust the form templates accordingly. All of your `modelMaster/create`, `model1/_form`, `model2/_form`-views create and render a new `CActiveForm` (and thus several `<form>` tags).

Since you cannot nest form-elements in html (how should html know which action to pass the data to) you have to avoid this by doing the following:

1. Extract the inputs of the form you want to nest into a new view, e.g. `model1/_formInputs` would look like

   ```
   ...
   <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
   <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name');
   <?php echo $form->error($model,'name');
   ...
   ```
2. alter the `model1/create` and the other views and get a reference to the form created there, by assigning the return of `$this->beginWidget` to the variable `$form` (if not already done):

   ```
   <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
       'id'=>'foo',
   )); ?>
   ```

   replace the former input fields with

   ```
   <?php $this->renderPartial('model1/_formInputs', array('form' => $form); ?>
   ```

   Now, for example the old `model1/create`-view should work as expected
3. To get your multi-model-form working you just have to get the reference to the form created in `modelMaster/create` and use it to renderPartial all `*/_formInputs` you require. Please also remember to include the models for the inputs into the renderPartial-call. So `modelMaster/create` would look something like:

   ```
   <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
       'id'=>'foo',
   )); ?>

   /* Master Inputs here */

   // Rendering other models' inputs
   <?php $this->renderPartial('model1/_formInputs', array('form' => $form, 'model' => $model1); ?>
   <?php $this->renderPartial('model2/_formInputs', array('form' => $form, 'model' => $model2); ?>

   /* Render Form Buttons here */

   <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Submit with Ajax, in Yii it is easy to do and it will keep things easy to understand in the controllers, each controller will have a save and respond with json to confirm the save. There is already ajax validation.

```
    /**
 * Performs the AJAX validation.
 * @param CModel the model to be validated
 */
protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='employee-form')
    {
        $valid = CActiveForm::validate($model);
        if(strlen($valid) > 2) {
            echo $valid;
            Yii::app()->end();
        }       
    }
}
```

As you can see I have modified it to return the error if there is one (validate returns [] if it is valid, I should probably check for that instead of strlen >2 ), otherwise let the script continue, in this case it will go to the save function.